# How to validate files in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, file, validation

It seems like some ios Devices (newer ones I believe, iPhones and iPads) and versions aren't able to validate files properly.
I'm trying to validate an image, a resume and 3 videos.

I keep getting one of these two errors:

```
"resume_id": [
            "The resume id must be a file of type: doc, docx, pdf."
        ]
```

And I always upload a .doc or pdf file.

Or

```
"video_one_id": [
            "The video one id must be a file of type: avi ,mpeg, mpeg4, mov."
        ]
"video_two_id": [
            "The video two id must be a file of type: avi ,mpeg, mpeg4, mov."
        ]
"video_three_id": [
            "The video three id must be a file of type: avi ,mpeg, mpeg4, mov."
        ]
```

And I always upload .mov files. I find usually this happens when I take a video on my iphone and upload it. My client also tried the same thing on his brand new iPad and also had no success.

Here is my code.

CandidateProfileRequest.php:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'date_of_birth' => 'required',
        'experience' => [
            'required',
            new MaxWordsRule(),
        ],
        'skills' => [
            'required',
            new MaxWordsRule(350),
        ],
        'job_title' => 'required',
        'resume_id' => 'required|file|mimes:doc,docx,pdf',
    ];

}
```

CandidateProfileController.php:

```
public function store(CandidateProfileRequest $request)
{
    if ($request->hasFile('video_one_id')
        && $request->hasFile('video_two_id')
        && $request->hasFile('video_three_id')
        && $request->hasFile('photo_id')) {
        $request->validate([
            'video_one_id' => 'file|mimes:avi ,mpeg, mpeg4, mov|max:30720',
            'video_two_id' => 'file|mimes:avi ,mpeg, mpeg4, mov|max:30720',
            'video_three_id' => 'file|mimes:avi ,mpeg, mpeg4, mov|max:30720',
            'photo_id' => 'image|mimes:jpeg, png, jpg|max:5120'
        ]);
    }
}
```

I also tried using mimetypes instead of mimes in my validation rules, but still I get the errors above.
On my Macbook Pro Laptop everything works, it's just on my iPhone and my clients iPad.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

you can validate file like this way

```
$validator = Validator::make([ 'pdf'      => $request->file('pdf'), 'extension' => strtolower($request->file('pdf')->getClientOriginalExtension()),
        ], ['pdf'          => 'required', 'extension'      => 'required|in:pdf,html,txt', ], ['pdf.required'          => 'This field is required', 'extension.required'      => 'This field is required','extension.in'      => 'This field only accept pdf,html,txt extension',]);
```

Comment: And then I would have to do this with each file type? Laravel should definitely fix this issue. Seems like we have to write extra code for something silly. But thank you for your answer!

Comment: What does the .in do on extension.in, on this line of code?
'extension.in' => 'This field only accept pdf,html,txt extension'

Comment: This didn't work for me unfortunately and it shows me no error, in logs or console. My success message comes through, but the data doesn't...